# How to use CA that signs the SSL Certificate

Tags: java, ssl, x509, jsse

I have read a lot of stuff regarding SSL certificates and still not clear.
Our webserver will connect to a third party server.
The 3rd party has sent us the CA (xxx.cer) that signs the SSL Certificate on their server. The steps I need to do (I think):

1. Add the xxx.cer to `cacert` file which exists on our server through `keytool`
2. In java code, I should be using a `TrustManager` to use the CA before I open the connection.

(2) is what I am not clear about. Can someone give me some direction?

Comment: have a look at [this example](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/evanx/archive/2015/02/13/explicit-trust-manager-self-signed-certificates)

Comment: There is a predefined list of trusted CA in your keystore, you dont have to import it unless you want to trust a self signed CA. And trust is usually between servers not application. (Unless you are making desktop application)

Comment: Unfortunately the link given is not working. Yes our Webserver is trying to connect to the third party server.

Comment: Can import this .cer file thru MS Managment console (mmc)?

Comment: You need to do (1) only. (2) is a substitute for (1), generally unnecessary.